# Why does Jetpack Compose not capitalize text in buttons?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The docs seem to think buttons should be all caps https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Typography#button but in practice, they aren't. (Using 1.0.0-beta01)

How can change my theme so button text is capitalized?

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be no property in the TextStyle class yet that allows you to set the uppercase.
The only workaround I have found is to modify my Typography theme for `button` and use the [fontFeatureSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle#fontFeatureSettings()) property of [TextStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextStyle) to set the small caps to all characters with `fontFeatureSettings = "c2sc, smcp"`

Example `Typography.kt`

```kotlin
val Typography = Typography(
    button = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = FontFamily.Default,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W500,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        fontFeatureSettings = "c2sc, smcp"
    )
)
```

From the docs

> The advanced typography settings provided by font. The format is the same as the CSS font-feature-settings attribute: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-feature-settings-prop

Note from [CSS font-variant Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-variant.asp)

> In a small-caps font, all lowercase letters are converted to uppercase letters. However, ***the converted uppercase letters appears in a smaller font size than the original uppercase letters*** in the text.

Not a very beautiful solution but it is something.
Tested with `1.1.0-alpha01`